# Facebook Feed Dialog not working as opening by Android Facebook APP

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a web application that share Custom result via Feed Dialog, the code is as simple as this:

```
<a href="https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=1676106989341658&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ef.co.kr/%2FCampaign%2F2016%2Fnewyear2016%2Ffrontend%2Fclose.html&display=touch&name=123&caption=123&description=%22%EC%A7%80%EA%B5%AC%EB%8A%94%20%EB%91%A5%EA%B7%B8%EB%8B%88%EA%B9%8C~%20%EC%98%A8%20%EC%84%B8%EC%83%81%20%EC%B9%9C%EA%B5%AC%EB%93%A4%20%EB%8B%A4%20%EB%A7%8C%EB%82%98%EA%B3%A0%20%EC%98%A4%EA%B2%A0%EB%84%A4~%E2%99%AC%22%20%0A%EC%97%AC%ED%96%89%EB%A7%8C%20%EA%B0%80%EB%A9%B4%20%ED%98%B8%EA%B8%B0%EC%8B%AC%20%ED%8F%AD%EB%B0%9C%2C%20%ED%8F%AD%ED%92%8D%20%EC%B9%9C%ED%99%94%EB%A0%A5%20%EB%B0%9C%ED%9C%98%ED%95%98%EB%8A%94%20%EB%82%98%EC%97%90%EA%B2%8C%20%EC%96%B4%EC%9A%B8%EB%A6%AC%EB%8A%94%20%EB%8F%84%EC%8B%9C%EB%8A%94%20%EC%84%B8%EC%9D%B8%ED%8A%B8%20%EC%A4%84%EB%A6%AC%EC%95%88%EC%8A%A4!%0A&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ef.co.kr%2Fcampaign%2Fdestination%2F&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.ef.com%2Fsitecore%2F__~%2Fmedia%2Fefcom%2Fcampaign%2F2016%2Fblood%2Fdestination%2FKR%2Fsharing_updated%2Fst-julians_FB_1200x627_JAN_16.jpg" target="_blank">SHARE</a>
```

It works perfectly on iOS and all browsers. However on Android, opening the link from a browser, and if I choose open the link with Facebook App, the sharing title and picture are not the same as in the query string.

Is it a bug of Facebook/Android?

Comment: It looks like a Facebook bug. We're experiencing the same behavior. What happens is that the app is taking the page's URL from your href, but then goes on to investigate the page for the open graph meta tags, instead of using the parameters you've sent along. We also installed an older version of the Facebook app to test this, and it DID work correctly there. It's a Facebook issue, introduced in one of the recent versions of their app.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/174757742889256/ I think this is the issue